# barcode scan method - native script with nativescript-barcodescanner

Tags: android, npm, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am developing an app for android devices with nativescript.
I'm trying to use the scan method in the plugin without any success.
Unfortunately this is the only barcode scanner plugin for nativescript.

I took the code from this playground:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=03Ge8E&v=5

the error which is thrown:

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=234, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {org.nativescript.blankng/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onRequestPermissionsResult failed
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=234, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {org.nativescript.blankng/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onRequestPermissionsResult failed
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4605)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4647)
System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onRequestPermissionsResult failed
System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1286)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1173)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1160)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1138)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1134)
System.err:     at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(NativeScriptActivity.java:72)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7941)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7763)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4598)
System.err:     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I just removed everything and recreated the project